# Add custom types typescript 3

Tags: typescript

The current behavior: I migrated from @types/openlayers": "4.6.17" to "@types/ol": "5.3.6" and I don't find the function getVectorContext(event) in ol/render so I added it manually to render.d.ts but the next npm install I will lose this modification

The wanted behavior: I want to add a file *.d.ts that contain a custom types to my project but I got the error :module not found can t resolve '/path/customtypes'

Comment: For the sake of completeness: I have [answered the question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58996141/2436655).